# iOS 7 music controls not working

Tags: music, ios

As soon as I updated my phone, my music controls stopped working. On the lock screen and in the Control Center, I can only change the volume, not the song. The buttons to change the song light up when I touch them but the song doesn't change. I have to go into the Music app to change the song every time. My screen isn't cracked or broken - it works perfectly fine. Please could I have some help on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your phone I was having the same problem, make sure to close ever app before turning your phone off. It's working for me at the moment but I've been having this problem since iOS 6 and also in iOS 7 now, so who knows how long it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with my 4S and tried turning my phone (all the way) off (by holding down the power button for 6 seconds …) and on (ditto) and it fixed the problem.  I did NOT have to quit my apps. (A good thing since that's done differently in IOS 7 … with swipe(s))

It happened right after I updated the OS to 7.0.2; perhaps that's true for others affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue on my iPhone 4, went to settings and deactivated the control center access while locked, closed settings completely and turned off my cellphone. Turned it on and now it works not sure if this will be temporal. Hope Apple fixes this bug ASAP.